# PSDK compiler is linking with system32\msvcrt.dll?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sdk, linker, msvcrt

I am compiling OpenSSL under `Windows XP 64` using `PSDK2003`.

There is a `/MD` flag in the compiler settings.

If the `PATH` environment variable contains `%SYSTEMROOT%/system32`, then compilation is successful.

But if I don't specify `%SYSTEMROOT%/system32`, then compilation fails with an error:

`error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __security_check_cookie`

In this case, if I specify the additional library `bufferoverflowu.lib`, then compilation will be successful again.

I really don't understand this behavior. Can you please explain why this happens?

I heard that the PSDK compiler, unlike the Visual Studio compiler, is linking with `system32\msvcrt.dll`. I really don't understand what this means? Can you please explain what means: linking with a system DLL? And what's the difference between linking in Visual Studio and PSDK? Is there NOT system `msvcrt.dll`? I know that `msvcr70.dll`, `msvcr80.dll`, etc are not system. But what about NOT system `msvcrt.dll`?

Does linking with a system DLL depend on the version of Windows?
Will anything change if I compile under Windows 10/11 (will this app work on older Windows 7/8)?